# How to update one key's value in a object in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I change only one key's value in [openWord] in useState, when I click on special button I want to change only one key's value i.e openWord.pol from false to true?

```
const [openWord, setOpenWord] = useState({
    pol: false,
    eng: false,
    ger: false
});
  const showWord = e => {
    let value = e.target.value; //in value is to choose pol,eng,ger
    setOpenWord(!openWord.pol); //-> setOpenWord(!openWord.value)
    console.log("openWord", openWord);
  };
```

Comment: As a side note: Your `console.log` may not show what you expect, even after you solve this, since setting the state is async and may not have completed before the log is called.

Comment: the answers below are correct, but just as some advice, in your scenario, I find it easier to just work with 3 separate states instead of one state object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOpenWord({...openWord, pol: !openWord.pol});` and you'll do just fine.

Comment: While this is correct, it's best to include some explanation as well as the code snippet, to help people understand what you have changed and why it will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [openWord, setOpenWord] = useState({
    pol: false,
    eng: false,
    ger: false
});
  const showWord = e => {
    let value = e.target.value; //in value is to choose pol,eng,ger
    setOpenWord({
      ...openWord,
      pol: !openWord.pol
    })
    console.log("openWord", openWord);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for help :)
I did if statement for all object when was executed

```
 const [openWord, setOpenWord] = useState({
    pol: false,
    eng: false,
    ger: false
  });
  const showWord = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    let value = e.target.value;
    console.log("value", value);
    if (value === "pol") setOpenWord({ ...openWord, pol: true });
    if (value === "eng") setOpenWord({ ...openWord, eng: true });
    if (value === "ger") setOpenWord({ ...openWord, ger: true });

    console.log("openWord", openWord.pol);
    return { value };
  };
```

Comment: You can simplify this by just doing `setOpenWord({ ...openWord, [value]: true });` assuming value is limited to pol, eng, ger.